# How do I remove some of the empty space at the top of tallbox.com?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I know it involves the css. I am not an expert programmer, and just know the very beginnings of html and CSS. I know how to go into the editor in wordpress, and make modifications, but I need to figure out how to make those modifications.

Comment: Please update your question to include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the HTML for all pages and delete the div `<div class="site-header-wrapper clear">` deleting this will remove the bar at the top.

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust the padding on line 951 on your style.css
.content-area { margin: 0 auto; max-width: 829.00001px; padding: 36px 36px 0; }